# dotnet SDK not installing in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu-22.04

I try to download dotnet SDK for C# with

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6
```

but it says

```
A fatal error occurred. The folder [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.110/host/fxr] does not exist
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Install .NET on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux)

Comment: Is that one line the only output you get? If not, please add more output, preferably the entire output of the command if it's not too large.

Comment: there is an installation [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588698/6482931) as a last resort situation.

Comment: [The installation docs for 22.04](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2204) don't mention any `dotnet6` package. It's either `dotnet-sdk-6.0` for the full SDK or `dotnet-runtime-6.0` for the runtime and `aspnetcore-runtime-6.0` for ASP.NET Core applications. Did you follow the

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A fatal error occurred. The folder \[/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr\] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753672/a-fatal-error-occurred-the-folder-usr-share-dotnet-host-fxr-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

```bash
sudo apt remove dotnet*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y dotnet6
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Dotnet SDK is already installed on the system try the following it will help

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And if prompted yes or no choose yes for the .net framework otherwise if you don't know what you are doing choose no, that command is going to upgrade all your installed software and the kernel, so, be careful if you are relying on some old specific version of packages for your software to run

maybe it will ask you to restart

Comment: apt upgrade is dangerous, don't

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` is a 'guns on sparrows' approach for the given problem and does not guarantee to fix it. Please improve or delete your answer because it could lead to unwanted package-upgrades and possible further problems.