# dotnet installation is not working properly

Tags: .net, installation, ubuntu-22.04, .net-runtime

I have been trying to install dotnet in 2-3 different ways. I have tried the steps given on Microsoft's dotnet official page and some other ways that I have found on web. All the time after installation when I give `dotnet --version` command then it shows:

> A fatal error occurred. The folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not exist this error.

I am using Linux as my operating system. More information is given below:

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
> Release:    22.04
> Codename:   jammy

The Steps i have followed to install dotnet is:

Step 1:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Step 2:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https 

sudo apt update 

sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Step 3:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https 

sudo apt update 

sudo apt install dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

Step 4:

```
dotnet --version
```

After the final step, I get the error. With Other ways I always get the same error what should I do? I have also used snap install. But the snap install version has major problems in configuration. I wasn't able to work in a project with the snap install version.

Can anyone provide me with a full installation process that will work in my system?

Comment: Which arch is this, x64 or ARM64?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A fatal error occurred. The folder \[/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr\] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753672/a-fatal-error-occurred-the-folder-usr-share-dotnet-host-fxr-does-not-exist)

Comment: *64 architecture and thanks for the the other link but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Can't replicate it on a fresh Ubuntu VM, if you can't nuke it try opening an issue in the dotnet github.

Answer (score 1):

I have been manually checking all file paths that can possibly have any dotnet SDK files. I have removed all of them. Auto removes any kind of app that is related to dotnet then did a clean install. Normally when I gave the dotnet install 6.0 command is used to download the 6.0.406 version but this time it installed the 6.0.113 version. But now it works on my system.

If anyone has a similar problem try removing all dotnet files and then reinstalling it.